# ios textfield bounces

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a few textfields in a grouped uitableview.
When you move focus from one textfield to another, the text in the textfield bounces up by a few pixels.
How do I get rid of this?
It might be because I changed the textfield height.

Comment: This may be intended behavior.  When one you move focus from a `TextField` in one cell to a `TextField` in another cell, the `TableView` should scroll up to put the current `TextField` above the keyboard when it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out: there was a problem with the font used (a custom font).

Answer (score 0):

you can use IQKeyBoardManager pod to solve this issue. 
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/4.0.2/

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```